# Play framework 2.0.2 SQL Server config

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have problem connect to SQL Server :

In my `application.conf` I have:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=testdb;user=sa;password=***;"
```

When I run the app I get an error:

> play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error
>   [Driver not found: [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]]

pl help me

Answer (score 3):

You need the Sql Server drivers in your classpath.  You can do that by creating a lib/ directory and placing the SQL Server driver jar in there, or updating your SBT dependencies.  See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SBTDependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the official MS SQL Server drivers https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

And then copy the driver jar `sqljdbc4.jar` to the lib folder under project root (as Adam mentioned before).